# Does "The Doctor, The Widow, and The Wardrobe" tie into the overall storyline, or can it be skipped?

Tags: doctor-who, suggested-order

I have recently been watching *Doctor Who* (after 2005 series). I have finished season 6 and the platform I am watching it on doesn't have the special, "The Doctor, The Widow, and the Wardrobe". Can I just skip the special if it is not important to the story arc in next series? No spoilers please as I'm watching it for the first time.

Comment: Story arc?  No.  But it does have some character beats at the end, related to his choices at the end of series 6.

Comment: @Radhil, If I skip it, would it have any major effect at my viewing experience? Also, if it would have, would reading the plot only suffice?

Comment: If they're missing this one, then they may be missing other specials, too - such as the five episodes with David Tennant between series 4 and 5. Those are incredibly valuable story episodes.

Comment: @HorusKol, Actually those specials were also available on youtube and I have watched those, but I couldn't find this one anywhere else.

Comment: You can yes. It doesn't affect anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you can freely skip all the main storyline of this episode.** It's a classic one-off Christmas special, involving characters that never appeared in any other episode. There's no recurring villains like Daleks or Cybermen, and no worldbuilding or scene-setting that's used later.

The only scene which does fit into a (sort of, to the extent there is one) overall series arc is the very last scene, after the main adventure with the one-off characters is over, when

> the Doctor goes to visit Amy and Rory. This is the first time they meet after he apparently died in the Series 6 finale "The Wedding of River Song".

Even that's not really important - just a bit of emotion, no big reveals or character development - but it's only 2 minutes long and you can easily watch it on Youtube:

Comment: Their door is the same shade of blue or near enough.

Comment: @Verdan Something old, something new, something borrowed, ...

Comment: Really thanks for the help....